# How to use the carpenter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-forestry

I'm trying to make a soldering iron using the carpenter, but it wont work as it keeps on showing "missing resources".My carpenter set-up using a BuildCraft sterling engine.My carpenter set-up using a BuildCraft sterling engine and i'm trying to make a soldering iron but "missing resources" keeps popping up, even when water meter is full.
[image: My carpenter set-up using a BuildCraft sterling engine.]

[image: Im trying to make a soldering iron but "missing resources" keeps popping up, even when water meter is full.]

Comment: I think you need to put the materials in the machine's inventory (the space above yours), and that the "crafting area" is just a pattern. I may be wrong, it's been a while since I've played Forestry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the crafting area for the carpenter is just for "dummy" items that show the recipe you wish to make. To actually make it, put the ingredients in the inventory below the crafting area and supply it with power.

Comment: To add to this, you should have noticed that it didn't take any items from the stack you were using to specify the recipe